# Best image format by Epson Scanner Software to use for Lightroom

Tags: film, jpeg, scanning, tiff, epson

Epson scanner app (for V600) scanner let us scan the image with 6
type of output. See the below table:

[image]

What's the best format I should use to get maximum editing ability in Lightroom?

Answer (score 5):

The only two viable options in the list are JPEG and TIFF.

- JPEG is fine for lossy compression, 8-bit/channel color, and smaller file sizes. I would use JPEG for paper originals that will not be heavily edited.
- TIFF supports 16-bit/channel images with lossless compression that can hold up better against extensive editing, but files tend to be very large. I would use TIFF for film originals.
- PNG is not in your list, but most scanner software do support it. Like TIFF, they support high bit-depth color and lossless compression. Files are usually a bit smaller than TIFF, but also take longer to process.

The following formats should be avoided:

- BMP and PCT – Platform specific formats that are usually not compressed. While they might work fine with Lightroom, you're just asking for problems later by using them.
- PDF – Document format that is capable of storing images, but *not* suitable for editing.
- Multi-TIFF – Like PDF, this format is intended for storing scanned multi-page documents. Image editors usually don't work well with multi-page documents.